# How to add a score counter in android game?

Tags: android, multithreading, image, counter

Hi I want to implement an 'image score counter' in my android game but it does not work well. However it compiles well but soon when ball reaches screen edge app returns error:

```
04-08 10:07:31.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8599): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1176
04-08
10:07:31.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8599): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 10:07:31.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8599):at com.Pong.GameState.update(GameState.java:154)
04-08 10:07:31.639: E/AndroidRuntime(8599):at com.Pong.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:41)
```

I got 3 files that menage the game:
GameState.java GameView.java GameThread.java:

The errors are in:

**GameState.java:**

```
TopCounter.setImageResource(myImageList[i+1]);
```

**GameThread.java:**

```
_state.update();
```

This is how GameThread.java looks like:

```
package com.Pong;

import....

    class GameThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private GameView gameView;
        private Paint _paint;
        private GameState _state;
        private boolean run = false;
        public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GameView gameView, Context context, Handler handler) {
            this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            this.gameView = gameView;
            _paint = new Paint();
            _state = new GameState();
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            this.run = run;
        }

        public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
            return surfaceHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas c;
            while (run) {
                c = null;

                try {
                    c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

                    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                         gameView.onDraw(c);
                        _state.update();  //here is the error
                        _state.draw(c, _paint);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


public GameState getGameState()
{
return _state;
}
}
```

This is how GameState.java looks like (I cut unnecessary lines):

```
package com.Pong;

Import ...

public class GameState extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gamestate);
        TopCounter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.counterT);
        BottomCounter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.counterB);

}
    int _screenWidth = 270;
    int _screenHeight = 395;   
    int _ballSize = 10;
    int _ballX = 100;
    int _ballY = 100;
    int _ballVelocityX = 3;
    int _ballVelocityY = 3;
    int _batLength = 75;
    int _batHeight = 10;
    int _topBatX = (_screenWidth / 2+25) - (_batLength / 2);
    int _topBatY = 54;
    int _bottomBatX = (_screenWidth / 2+25) - (_batLength / 2); 
    int _bottomBatY = 392;
    int i=0;
    // under is matrix that contains images to my counter.
    int[] myImageList = new int[]{
            R.drawable.counter00,
            R.drawable.counter01,
            R.drawable.counter02,
            R.drawable.counter03,
            R.drawable.counter04,
            R.drawable.counter05,
            R.drawable.counter06,
            R.drawable.counter07,
            R.drawable.counter08,
            R.drawable.counter09
            };
    ImageView TopCounter;
    ImageView BottomCounter; 

    public GameState()
    {}

    public void update() {

        _ballX += _ballVelocityX;
        _ballY += _ballVelocityY;


    if( _ballY > _screenHeight){
            _ballX = _screenWidth/2;
            _ballY = _screenHeight/2;
            TopCounter.setImageResource(myImageList[i+1]); //here is the error
            _toppoint=_toppoint+1;
            _topBatX =_screenWidth/2-10;
            _bottomBatX =_screenWidth/2-10;
            }       

        if( _ballY < 50){
            _ballX = _screenWidth/2;
            _ballY = _screenHeight/2;
            BottomCounter.setImageResource(myImageList[i+1]);
            _bottompoint=_bottompoint+1;
            _topBatX =_screenWidth/2-10;
            _bottomBatX =_screenWidth/2-10;
            } 
        if (_toppoint==9){

        } 
        else if (_bottompoint==9) {

        }

        if(_ballX > _screenWidth || _ballX <= 40){
            _ballVelocityX *= -1;
            }
        if(_ballX > _topBatX && _ballX < _topBatX+_batLength && _ballY < _topBatY){
            _ballVelocityY *= -1;
        }
        if(_ballX > _bottomBatX && _ballX < _bottomBatX+_batLength && _ballY > _bottomBatY){
            _ballVelocityY *= -1;
        }
        if (_ballX == 40+_batLength) {
            _topBatX=40;
            } else if (_ballX > 40+_batLength && _ballX <=  _screenWidth){
                _topBatX=_ballX-_batLength+6;
                } 
        if (_bottomBatX < 46) {
            _bottomBatX=46;
        } else if (_bottomBatX+_batLength > _screenWidth){
            _bottomBatX=_screenWidth-_batLength+6;
        }
        }
    public void draw(Canvas c, Paint paint) {
    paint.setARGB(255, 234, 222, 199);
    c.drawRect(new Rect(_ballX,_ballY,_ballX + _ballSize,_ballY + _ballSize), paint);
    c.drawRect(new Rect(_topBatX, _topBatY, _topBatX + _batLength, _topBatY + _batHeight), paint); //top bat
    c.drawRect(new Rect(_bottomBatX, _bottomBatY, _bottomBatX + _batLength, _bottomBatY + _batHeight), paint); //bottom bat
    }


}
```

In my XML file:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/counterT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/counter00"
       android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
         />
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/counterB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/counter00" />
```

Can anybody help ?

Comment: Create application variable

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem in GameState.java file

```
// under is matrix that contains images to my counter.
int[] myImageList = new int[]{
        R.drawable.counter00,
        R.drawable.counter01,
        R.drawable.counter02,
        R.drawable.counter03,
        R.drawable.counter04,
        R.drawable.counter05,
        R.drawable.counter06,
        R.drawable.counter07,
        R.drawable.counter08,
        R.drawable.counter09
        };
```

this is not how you declare a Matrix! you want an array of integers 
try to declare it as :

```
int[] myImageList = {
    R.drawable.counter00,
    R.drawable.counter01,
    R.drawable.counter02,
    R.drawable.counter03,
    R.drawable.counter04,
    R.drawable.counter05,
    R.drawable.counter06,
    R.drawable.counter07,
    R.drawable.counter08,
    R.drawable.counter09
    };
```

EDIT:

```
    if (TopCounter != null){
       TopCounter.setImageResource(myImageList[i]);
       i++;
    }
```

also you don't increment you list index, it always equals 0, instead of that
initialize the index to 1 and then when you change the image source increment it by 1
but you'll also need to check that the index doesn't exceed the list size

Comment: try to add an if statement to check if TopCounter is null and debug it.. see me edited answer

Comment: same :( I think this is about the thread and state.update() fail.

Comment: when do you debug this, is TopCounter was null? did you check it?

Comment: one more thing.. you need to extends runable and not thread
read here http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/500.html

Comment: @NightKn8 are you sure that after u change the code as I suggest you get the same error? post your logcat after the changes..

Comment: but the error tells you that there is a null exception, caused by
gameState.update().. the line is TopCounter.setImageResource(list[i+1])
did you even debug this? see if it worked and crashed after some time or is it crashed as it start to set the image resource?